# Python Selenium: Clicking Buttons and Error 404

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have this program that is scraping products from Lowes's website. I am trying to make it so that I can also see the products that are currently unavailable so  can scrape those as well.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def scrape_page_data():
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')))
    container = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pl')

    # scroll down to load all content on the page
    for _ in range(4):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 2000);")
        time.sleep(2)

    skus = container.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'tooltip-custom')
    prices = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.prdt-actl-pr')
    description = container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.titl-cnt.titl.brnd-desc')

    return skus, prices, description


def pagination(url, pages=1):
    prod_num = []
    prod_price = []
    prod_desc = []
    page_num = 0
    # iterate over the pages
    for i in range(1, pages + 1):
        # print(f"this is page {i}")
        driver.get(f"{url}?offset={page_num}")

        skus, prices, description = scrape_page_data()
        for sku in skus:
            prod_num.append(sku.text)
        for price in prices:
            prod_price.append(price.text)
        for desc in description:
            prod_desc.append(desc.text)

        print(f"prod_num: {prod_num}")
        print(f"prod_price: {prod_price}")
        print(f"prod_desc: {prod_desc}")
        print(f"prod_num: {len(prod_num)}")
        print(f"prod_price: {len(prod_price)}")
        print(f"prod_desc: {len(prod_desc)}")

        # increment it by 24 since each page has 24 data
        page_num += 24
        time.sleep(1)

    return prod_num, prod_price, prod_desc


def click_show_unavailable_button():
    try:
        unavailable_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'styles__StyledSVG-sc-1houmlx-0 hGNiQH icon icon-plus')
        unavailable_button.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'styles__StyledSVG-sc-1houmlx-0 hGNiQH icon icon-plus')))
        filter_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'CheckboxWrapper-j2pgcr-0 ikAusL')
        filter_button.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.CLASS_NAME, 'CheckboxWrapper-j2pgcr-0 ikAusL')))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to click the 'Show Unavailable Products' button:", str(e))


# set the website URL and initialize the Chrome driver
website = 'https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-joint-compound-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858286'
options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--geolocation=47.8410,-122.2947")  # set geolocation to Lynnwood, WA
driver = uc.Chrome()

click_show_unavailable_button()
# call the pagination function to scrape data and store it in three separate lists
prod_num, prod_price, prod_desc = pagination(website, pages=3)

# convert the three lists to a pandas dataframe and save it as a CSV file
df = pd.DataFrame({'code': prod_num, 'price': prod_price, 'brand': prod_desc})
df.to_csv('lowesjctest.csv', index=False)
print(df)

# quit the Chrome driver
driver.quit()
```

I have the click_show_unavailable_button function trying to click the proper buttons to filter but it does not seem to be working. Why is that? I have also tried changing the website link from https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-joint-compound-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858286 to https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-joint-compound-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858286?refinement=1 once it is filtered but this just gives me an Error 404. If anyone could help me find a solution that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those links do not give a 404 error when I click on them.  I don't understand your question.

Comment: @JohnGordon when I put https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-joint-compound-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858286?refinement=1 into my code I get an error 404 even though the link seems to work just fine when I paste it into chrome. So to counter this I tried to make a function that manually clicks through the page to filter on the 'show unavailable products' button, but that does not seem to be working as well. the original link for the page is https://www.lowes.com/pl/Drywall-joint-compound-Drywall-Building-supplies/4294858286